# What is the most efficient data structure to calculate moving averages?

Tags: performance, perl, data-structures, quantitative-finance

When working on the stock market, calculated indicators that include 28-day averages, 14-day averages, etc. need to be calculated.

Furthermore every day the average needs to update to include the latest day's close/high/low/volume.

Now often the array needs to be looped through to find the sum, average, max, and min values.

I though that a queue (in the form of a dynamic array or linked list or anything else you can think of) seems like the perfect data structure for this based on the FIFO method of entry/exit.

Questions:

1. How does the efficiency and scalability of queues compare to hashes?
2. When running a Perl script the queue will not be in memory and will therefore have to be initialized and worked on (values initialized from a CSV file), I know this is pretty unrelated, but which data structure would be the best to use with a Perl script that executes on a daily schedule?

Comment: Have you see this finance module in perl? http://search.cpan.org/~kmx/Finance-TA-v0.4.1/TA.pod

Answer (score 2):

With [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) you can take a slice of a larger "array" (1D matrix) then do statistics on that slice, then take another slice and repeat. PDL has many built-in statistical functions and if that isn't enough, there is the add-on [PDL::Stats](http://pdl-stats.sourceforge.net/)!

PDL is like MatLab or NumPy (better we think!) for Perl. It's highly optimized for "looping" over numerical arrays. I put "loop" in quotes because these loops are implemented at the C level (sounds speedy eh?). Take a peek!

Comment: Sounds great. Do you have moving average function in  PDL::Stats? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 1):

Not enough information here.  Are you processing an entire days worth of quotes to get your daily high/low/last?

Are you doing the averages on a per instrument basis?

With any moving average, you can just use a list of values that make up the sum of the average.  As a new value gets added, one drops off, and recalculate.

So a hash of lists if your doing by instrument and calculate on the fly.

Comment: I add a line to the CSV with close/high/low at the close of the day...the data is scraped from a feed. The averages are calculated per share, at the end of the day and inputted into a db...after which indicators are calculated using the values. Possibly an even better way to do it is to just save the 28th and 14th days close...then when updating (add new close to the old moving average and subtract the 28th / 14th stored value. Wait I dunno

Comment: @user1439659 That works, and is more or less how you do it.  Keep the sum, then do the add/subtract/divide.  Just didn't know how you were deriving the data.  Things change when you have to rip through 1.5 billion records vs. having the closing values.

Answer (score 1):

What is most efficient really depends.

- **Hashes** are unordered. They can look up values in nearly-constant time by a string key. A lookup is computationally expensive, and at least an order of magnitude slower than an array lookup. How well a hash performs depends on the number of "buckets" and the number of keys. However, a hash lookup will be faster than looping through an array to find an element for all non-trivial cases. Hashes require more space than an array.
- **Arrays** in Perl have both the characteristics of an array (random access) and a doubly linked list (via push, pop, shift, unshift). They are easy to use, and fast enough. If more than one element is to be added/removed, either use a slice, or the `splice` function. `splice` is a generalisation of `push` .. `unshift`, and is faster than looping.
- **Strings** can be used to store an array of integers. This is extremely efficient, but also quite limited (only ints).

  ```
  my $string = "";
  my $i = ~ 0; # a really big number
  $string .= chr $i; # get character from integer
  # Access elements via `substr`:
  my $j = ord substr $string, -1, 1; # last element; ord gets an int from a char
  ```

  Using Strings has the characteristics of an array (random access) and of a single linked list (appending is simple with `.=`). Other operations are reasonably fast as well (`substr` has many uses).

The pragmatic programmer will **use arrays** for most sequential data. He can also leverage the efficient functions from `List::Util` and `List::MoreUtils` that provide functions like `sum`, `average`, `max` and `min` (written in C for speed).

When you are building a list of values, and only need a fixed amount, either do this when you add a new element:

```
push @array, $new_value;
shift @array if @array > $max_length; # keep constant length
```

This is space-efficient but may be slower than simply building the list, and doing

```
splice @array, 0, -$max_length; # remove all but $max_length last elems
```

To access only a certain part of the array (without allocating a new variable), use slices:

```
use List::Util qw/sum/;
my $last_24_sum = sum @array[-24 .. $#$array];  sum the last 24 elems
```

If you want to use hashes, but know all possible fields at compile time, you can define constant names for the fields, and use an array instead. So don't do

```
my $hashref = { foo => $x, bar => $y }; # requires a lot of space
$hashref->{foo}; # slooow
```

but do

```
use constant {
    EL_FOO => 0, # make sure the integer range is continouus
    EL_BAR => 1, #   Perl doesn't have native enums
};
my $arrayref = [$x, $y];
$arrayref->[EL_FOO]; # faster!
```

instead.

When working with deeply nested data, it can sometimes pay off to cache nested references instead of recalculating them at every access:

```
# disputable
for my $i (...) {
  for my $j (...)
    do_something_with $x->[$i][$j][$_] for 1 .. 1e3;
  }
}
# possibly better
for my $i (...) {
  for my $j (...) {
    my $aref = $x->[$i][$j];
    do_something_with $aref->[$_] for 1 .. 1e3;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I think a singly linked list would be most efficient with FILO (first in, last out). EG. I get the close for a particular day, that becomes head node of list, then the previous 28th falls off end of list and the moving average can be calculated again. Instead of inserting into a db, and calculating the 28 day moving average from there. Hang on that is the same thing...

Comment: @user1439659 That would be a FIFO, not a FILO. Don't model FIFOs yourself (this is very inefficient), but use the builtin arrays. Those implement the characteristics of a double linked list. You will have to assert the fixed length yourself. See my first code example after "use arrays". Any way: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thanks Amon. "premature optimization is the root of all evil" Yes it is like procrastinating. Well I know who to ask when I do face problems or when I scale up to all world markets

Answer (score 1):

If you are calculating these things once a day... use the easiest data structure to code! Does it really take so much time to compute? If yes, go on reading.

The sum and average might be easier. If what you add are integers, you can use a FIFO and keep the sum in a variable. Whenever you insert or remove an element, update the sum accordingly (add or subtract).

If you add floating point values, then the method described above might lead to cumulative errors. This might happen if the values are of very different magnitudes and/or the series is very long. In this case, you would need something more complicated (see below).

For the max and min, the most efficient data structures are [max/min-heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap). Note that you can embed them in arrays. You would need to have them cross-referenced with the elements of the FIFO queue in order to find immediately the element that has to be removed every time.

The most general solution would be an augmented self-balanced tree. Augmented data structures are explained in chapter 14 of "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein. Basically, the tree would contain one element of your data sequence in every node. Every node would contain also the sum, min and max of its subtree. Every time you update a node, you have to update the sum, max and min in all the path from that node to the root. in the root you have the global sum, max and min.

You can find a C++ implementation of augmented self-balanced trees [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/avl-array/).

Though, since you only want the sum, min and max of a fixed number of elements, and you always insert at one end and remove at the other, you can make it much simpler. You only need a **circular buffer** and an array-embedded tree (see [how to embed such tree in an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Heap_implementation)). The tree would contain partial sum, min and max values, as in the augmented trees described before. The advantage is that you don't need to rebalance the tree because you never insert/remove in the middle of the sequence, and the tree always has the same size.

In order to have the statistics for the last 28 days, the last 14 days, the last week, and the last 3 days (for example), you would use a circular buffer and an array-embedded tree for every period: one for the last 3 days, another for the previous 4 (7 minus 3) days, another for the previous 7 days, and so on. Every day, you would take the last datum of every buffer and insert it in the next one.

Comment: Thanks for your input. There are +- 470 shares, about 10 calculations each. I haven't tested but I think it may take significant time to compute. The easiest to code would be inserting records into db daily and computing from there. If I were to use some of the data structures you suggest, would it be feasible to store 470 of these data structures in memory for the whole day only to be updated once a day?

Comment: @user1439659 There is only one way to find out (I don't know the exact amount of data, the data structure, your OS, hardware, Perl compilation flags…). The numbers you provide look reasonable even for low-powered machines, but I wouldn't keep the data in memory all the time. It might be best to write working code, and then optimize for speed and/or memory once you can test and profile working code. But no earlier. Premature optimization…

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple `%hash` with keys being some stringified or numericized representation of the timestamp and the value being what your data is associated with that time series item.  You can sort the keys of the hash, e.g.

```
#numeric
@srtdKeys = sort{$a<=>$b}(keys(%hash));
```

or

```
#string
@srtdKeys = sort(keys(%hash));
```

and loop through the last 28 or 14 etc. then retrieve the values from the hash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're completely rebuilding your data from scratch every run, perhaps you should look into [Statistics::Descriptive](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Statistics-Descriptive-3.0604/lib/Statistics/Descriptive.pm).

Shame you're getting this as a CSV.  With access to a Database Server, you could get this info with a couple SQL queries.